# How to obtain min or max of a 3-dimensional array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, unnest

How do I find the maximum (or minimum) element of a 3-dimensional array in PostgreSQL?

Is there any function or faster way instead of this?:

```
min:= A[1][1][1];

for i IN 1..9 LOOP
for j IN 1..9 LOOP
for k IN 1..9 LOOP
        min := least(min,A[i][j][k]);
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`unnest()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT min(elem) AS min_elem
FROM   unnest(my_arr) AS elem
```

`unnest()` returns a set of *base* elements regardless of array dimensions. Then all you need is the aggregate function `min()`.

As plpgsql assignment (since you seem to be working with plpgsql):

```
SELECT min(elem) INTO my_variable
FROM   unnest(my_arr) AS elem
```